# Redirection order

Tags: linux, bash, redirection

What is the difference between:

> command > file-name 2>&1

and

> command 2>&1 > file-name

Why does for e.g (asumming there is no `xxx` file).

> ls xxx > 1.txt 2>&1

works while

> ls xxx 2>&1 > 1.txt

doesn't?

Comment: There is a nice illustrated tutorial at [Illustrated Redirection Tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial) which makes all thiseasier to understand

Answer (score 1):

The order of redirections is significant. For example, the command

```
ls > dirlist 2>&1
```

directs both standard output (file descriptor 1) and standard error (file descriptor 2) to the file dirlist, while the command

```
ls 2>&1 > dirlist
```

directs only the standard output to file dirlist, because the standard error was made a copy of the standard output before the standard output was redirected to dirlist.

(Quoted from the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html))